# Are the quests/storyline optional?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I do not really like quests.

In SWTOR how much of the storylines/quests do I need to do?

I understand from the beta I had to do a long quest line to unlock the space ship and first companion.

EDIT: I feel I should comment here to explain the reason for the question, because it seems apparent to me that if you ask three people why they play the game, you will get 3 different answers, and I can't understand why people are fighting over which one is correct - THEY ALL ARE.

I play to socialise and to raid. I find it difficult to relate to the storylines of the quests and I do not like the railroading associated with storylines.

Thank you all for information and answers. I have accepted the one I felt was best because that is the way the site works, but I think all the answers are valid and each one taught me something.

Comment: -1. "I do not like [most of the content of this game.] Can/should I play it anyway?" It's not explicitly off topic, but it's a Bad Question that will invite Bad Answers.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I agree, though am kind of of the fence. The question itself in the header is valid ("Are the quests optional?"), but the body of the question and the comment about not liking quests invites discussion about it.

Comment: @Sterno let me be clear: I don't think this question is off topic or should be closed. I think it should be *downvoted*.

Comment: There is an endgame and a lot of people are more interested in raiding than questing. I have a number friends spacebar'ed through every quest to get to max level. I think it's a valid question and shouldn't be down voted.

Comment: You, sir, make me sad. Playing a Bioware game without enjoying the quests is about the saddest thing I've ever heard. I hear that Minesweeper doesn't have quests. Maybe play that?

Comment: Why all the hate? Someone asked a valid question and got flamed for it. I just proposed an alternate reason for why some people may enjoy playing this game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to do your class quests at a minimum if you want to unlock the full compliment of companions, which is important if you want to keep your crew skills up to date. You'll need to do them through at least level 15 or so to get your ship to be able to get to planets other than the starter areas as well.

Questing is also one of the few reliable ways to bring in credits, and at high levels, skill training becomes extremely pricey.

You *can* play with a minimum of questing, but the hoops you'll end up jumping through may make it not worth doing.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it has the information requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

if you don't like questing, you're playing the wrong game. I suggest you look for the revival of Star Wars Galaxies (google for it).

But if you're dead set on playing TOR, you can do just the class quests (ignore all the quest givers), and get your exp from PvP or space combat. With the money you get from space combat you should be able to buy your equipment in the AH and keep yourself updated.

You don't even need to do the class quests after you get your companion and ship (about level 10), just do space combat or pvp, but then, you'd be missing out on the best part of this game and what sets it apart from other MMOs.

Comment: +1 for "You're playing the wrong game".  How could you even remotely think this could be the right game?  Have you just not played a Bioware game before? >.>

Comment: Yes questing and the storyline are a big part of this game, but not the only part. I like playing online with my friends, I like playing the GTN, I like FPs and OPs, I like PVP, I like space battles. None of those are questing so I guess I'm playing the wrong game too.

Comment: you are indeed. WoW has better "FPs", a much better "GTN", much better PvP, and for space battles you can download any $1 app for your phone and you'd be better off.

Comment: @rodolfo yeah, but then you'd have to be a wow player, and that stink don't wash off.

Comment: To correct, your ship comes about lvl 17

Comment: @Fredy31 Getting the ship isn't level based -  it's tied to completion of the class quest chain on Coruscant/Dromund Kaas. While it can be as late as level 20 if you're doing every quest, since this question is about someone who is *explicitly avoiding them*, we can safely assume that they'll get the ship *much* sooner doing the absolute minimum number of class quests.

Comment: @Shinrai I could just as soon respond to your comments about Bioware by asking if you've *just not played an MMO before*? There are plenty of reasons to play the game that have nothing to do with the narrative and cutscenes. I don't think this is a great question for a whole host of reasons, but the fact that Bioware is known for narrative-centric game design isn't one of them at all.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - I agree with regards to the MMO genre, but I think expecting Bioware to make plot the same afterthought as it is in most MMOs (frankly I think it's LAUGHABLE in most MMOs) is only something I'd expect somebody unfamiliar with the company to do.  I did not mean to suggest that there aren't other things to do in the game, but I do agree with the original answer that you'll be missing a majority of the content, which wouldn't be the case with a lot of games.  (Really, I was saying the same thing your comment on the question does, just not as eloquently.)

Answer (score 5):

Technically, **yes**, but for a game like SWTOR, I would say that the Storylines are THE most important part of the game.  Period.

If you do plan on skipping all of the good stuff in the game, please do not go whining on the SWTOR forums about the game being too short and boring.  Or that there is no "end game" content.  The content is all the stuff you skipped on the way to lv 50.

I'm sure you won't like my opinion on this, but I've seen too many MMO's ruined by similar type thinking.

WoW and Warhammer being the largest two that I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Swtor has a few diffrent types of quest chains and all of them are optional except the basic game tutorial (levels 1-10, along with your starting planet quests.) Once you breach the level ten mark, you can choose which class direction you will be taking and the entire game is open to you at that point. (Actually, if you can convince somebody with a higher level avatar to kill everthing and help you run through your class stuff, you could make it up to the fleet and into a pvp match as early as level 5, although I am going to have to make an alt to confirm that.)

You do not need to quest to get your ship as long as you are willing to bum rides on other people, although if you are devoted to no questing, I can't see why you would possibly need to get to any of the other planets. The Imperial fleet has everything a fine solo pvper like yourself could possibly need. You make more than enough per pvp match to repair your gear and you have the GTN to buy anything you might need that you can't obtain from the pvp gear vendors.

If you can stomach questing until you get your first and second companions, you can go down to the crew skill trainers and pick up two of the Mission based gather skills and send your companions out on those to generate even more supplemental income for all that gear you are going to have to buy since you aren't going to get the normal free gear that people get as quest rewards.  The good news is that pvp gear is the equal of the other high level gear in the game, so if you decide to something else at fifty you will be able to.

Additionally, at a mininium of ten grand experience per ten minutes, pvp is one of the fastest way to chug down experience, so you should be hitting fifty faster than any other way (looking at my experience/time with my questing alt, which is mostly solo, with few flash points thrown in and some crafting to get to 400, I am getting about 3000 experience every ten minutes while actively questing.)

I will update this with more firm facts & figures once I run to fifty doing the pvp only.

Comment: You can't queue for Warzones before level 10, regardless of whether you've made it out of Korriband/Hutta/Ord Mantell/Tython. And a ship is needed, even for someone who is primarily PVP and endgame centric, if for no other reason than to access major world pvp hubs like Ilum, along with the associated vendors of endgame gear. The ship is important unless you have friends on at all times who can ferry you around.

Comment: You can blow through the ship quest in a few minutes at fifty when you are likely to go to ilum, for the main part of your leveling it is unnecessary. I can't imagine doing anything else with my pvp alt other than logging on and queueing, which is all I have been doing with my repubilic character as I grew bored with the class quest. Didn't know if you could pick up the quest early or not as the mininiun requirement for all the other quests on the fleet are min 1, recommended 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your class story quests on the first planet to unlock the quests on the second planet and to get your first companion.
You need to do your class story quests on the second planet to unlock the rest of the galaxy.

---

You don't need a companion or a ship to do group instance or pvp content.  You can run to the shuttle from the starting planet at level 1, but the group and pvp content starts at ~10.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have to quest to an extent or not depends on what you wish to do on the way to and at level 50.

If you don't plan on questing  but are going to PvP then you will not need a companion as you can't use them in PvP matches.

You don't NEED the companion in PvE as you can grind on mobs you can handle solo on your  way to level 50.

EDIT: You will need to quest to get your ship though(you get this around level 16-17ish).